# Multiple checkboxes with unique ID's through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I'm working on a website which should be done any time now, but I've got a new task to complete where I need to **check check-boxes** to simply **archive** news items. Or "blog posts" if you like.

The idea is to have a check-box on every blog post and if you check that check-box, the post **should be archived**. (This is in admin mode only).

I need ajax to do the job, but I haven't learned that yet. The PHP part is no problem.

Well the **problem** really is that I don't know how to **pass the unique ID** of every check-box, to the JavaScriptfunction and then to the PHP function.

OK, I have a set of blog posts, witch check-boxes, like so:

```
<div class="news_item">
    <input name="checkbox_blog" id="checkbox1" value="1" type="checkbox"  />
</div>

<div class="news_item">
    <input name="checkbox_blog" id="checkbox2" value="1" type="checkbox"  />
</div>
```

and so on. The Id's are populated from the ID from MySQL.

I have some kind of plugin for ajax checkboxes, but it will only work for one checkbox.

It's basically like this:

```
$("#checkbox").change(function() { 
    if($(this).is(":checked")) { 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'admin/archive_it',
            type: 'POST'
        });
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'admin/dont_archive_it',
            type: 'POST'
        });
    }
});
```

Works great on one check-box, but I have no idea how to proceed.

Any tips?

I think it's OK that it uses two different php-scripts for checking and un-checking the blog-posts, it doesn't really matter, I only want it to start working with different check-boxes.

Thanks!

**Solution:**

I changed the id's to classes, and used Arun P Johny's code:

```
$('.checkbox_blog').change(function () {
$.ajax({
    url: this.checked ? 'admin/archive_it' : 'admin/dont_archive_it',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        id: this.value
    }
    });
});
```

And because I'm using CodeIgniter, and have the CSRF-security option turned on, I had to add this to the data:

```
<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?> : '<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash()?>',
```

And now it works perfectly! Thanks all!

Comment: you can have same class to multiple checkboxes and use that for change function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are almost there, except that there were few things which you may need to take care ,like

1. add a generic class for all the checkboxes, so that the below event handler will work fine for all checkboxes.
2. there is no need to keep multiple ajax call references, although url is the only differentiator,so i have refined your code and even corrected few things which i noticed .

**JS CODE:**

```
$(".checkbox").on('change',function() { 
         var chkBit=$(this).is(":checked");
         var url;

        if(chkBit) 
            tarUrl='admin/archive_it';
        else
            tarUrl='admin/dont_archive_it';

        $.ajax({
                url: tarUrl,
                type: 'POST',
                success:function(){
                      //when the call is successful do something
                }
            });

 });`
```

Comment: Thanks! This among other answers helped me fix it! Thanks for the fast answer and the knowledge. Merry Christmas

Comment: Thats good,may be now you can close this Question from SO`s Question pool by selecting this answer as solution. Merry Christmas to you too bro :)

Comment: The only thing is that it doesn't have any "blog post ID" in the code. So there's no way I can know which post is gonna be archived. I tried doing like Arun P Johny said, and doing the value of the checkbox in the ajax "data". But I can't get that to work either.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for an ID here, use a class attribute to group the check boxes and give the database id as the value of the checkbox

```
<div class="news_item">
    <input name="checkbox_blog" class="checkbox_blog" value="1" type="checkbox" />
</div>
<div class="news_item">
    <input name="checkbox_blog" class="checkbox_blog" value="2" type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

then in the write change handlers for the `.checkbox_blog` elements, and pass the id of the database item to to archived or not as a parameter to the server side PHP

```
$('.checkbox_blog').change(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.checked ? 'admin/archive_it' : 'admin/dont_archive_it',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            id: this.value
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I was just typing the exact same answer lol... oh well nevermind :(

Comment: Thanks alot! I was reading through the answers, and this seems to be the best solution for me. Thanks for answering so fast and sharing your knowledge!

Comment: I've been trying now for a bit and I can't get the function to fire the ajax call. And I can't find the data that the ajax function sends. When I try to alert "this.value" I get nothing. tips?

Comment: @SimonAsp did you change the ids to class? also whether the check checkboxes are create after page load

Comment: yep, the ajax function works when i remove "data:" from the js. But the server side does nothing. I try to send a message back from the php-script but i get nothing. The console says: "POST admin/archive_it 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: I found the problem! It was because I'm using CodeIgniter and needed a CSRF hash in the data. Phew, I nearly gave up.

Answer (score 0):

Give all your checkboxes same class and then on change of any checkbox pass the ids of the checkboxes that are selected using the data attribute(probably by iterating over all the checkboxes with the class and collecting the ids of the ones that are checked)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="checkbox_blog" id="checkbox1" value="1" type="checkbox" onClick="YourFunction()"  />
<input name="checkbox_blog" id="checkbox2" value="1" type="checkbox" onClick="YourFunction()"  />


function YourFunction(){
if($(this).is(":checked")) { 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'admin/archive_it',
            type: 'POST'
        });
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'admin/dont_archive_it',
            type: 'POST'
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are dead-set on using id from checkbox, you can pass `data` like so: (note the change to selector `$("input[id^=checkbox]")`

```
$("input[id^=checkbox]").change(function() { 
    if($(this).is(":checked")) { 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'admin/archive_it',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                id: $(this).attr('id').split('checkbox')[1]
            }
        });
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'admin/dont_archive_it',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                id: $(this).attr('id').split('checkbox')[1]
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I was just thinking blurry, I'm not dead-set on that, but thanks alot!!